# javascript - Fullscreen rectangle in Canvas (Android/iOS web app)

Tags: javascript, canvas, web, html5-canvas

I have a problem trying to render a rectangle over the entire browser viewport using Canvas. The code below works fine on desktop, but on mobile devices (tested on iPad mini, Nexus 7 and Galaxy S4), the rectangle only fills a part of the screen (roughly a half on iPad, two thirds on other devices).

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.fill();
```

I tried ctx.scale(1, 1); but that did not work. The values of window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight are correct. And I get the same result even if I use a hardcoded value as the rectangle's width/height.

**Solution:**

based on answer by [Ken Fyrstenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/ken-fyrstenberg)

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var width = window.innerWidth * ratio;
var height = window.innerHeight * ratio;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pixel aspect ratio as a factor when calculating the canvas size.

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var width = window.innerWidth * ratio;
var height = window.innerHeight * ratio;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

CSS:

```
#canvasID {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! However, I had to modify your solution slightly, as what you posted did not work exactly the way it should. The CSS proved to be unnecessary, and I only used the first three lines of your code, using the calculated width and height to draw the rectangle (the working code is now in my original post).

Answer (score 0):

You might try ensuring that your `html` and `body` elements are all the full width and height of the viewport. Include any ancestors between the `canvas` and `body` as well. See the following CSS code:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```