# How to optimize canvas circle for retina devices?

Tags: javascript, canvas, retina, pixel-ratio

Please tell me how to make canvas look sharp for retina devices?
I would be grateful if you show in my example - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/ktygveh4/8/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('timer');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 105;
var endPercent = 100;
var curPerc = 0;
var counterClockwise = false;
var circ = Math.PI * 2;
var quart = Math.PI / 2;
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837326/javascript-fullscreen-rectangle-in-canvas-android-ios-web-app/28843722#28843722

Comment: Thanks! You can check my example? I'm not sure what made correctly http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/ktygveh4/9/